# How do I write a function that applies the "+" operator to a collection of generic values?

Tags: c#, generics

I've got a function that's supposed to add up a bunch of generics, if possible. 
Otherwise, it returns the value of the last generic it saw. 
I'd like to loop through my list of generics, try adding them, and then catch an exception if/when they can't be added.
I understand that you can't try any opperators on a generic, but I can't understand why.
Isn't attempting a certain method that may fail exactly why try catch was build for?

I'm pretty sure there isn't an easy way around this, but if there is, let me know.

Also, the offending code:

```
T getValueAtTime(float time)
{
    T toReturn = officalValue.Value;

    float maxValue;
    velocities.Sort();
    foreach(ValueAtTime<T> toAdd in velocities)
    {
        if(toAdd.AtTime < time)
        {
            try
            {
                toReturn += toAdd.Value;
            }
            catch(OpperatorUnavailableError err)
            {
                toReturn = toReturn + toAdd.Value;  
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                toReturn = toAdd.Value; 
            }
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: I'm treally not understanding what you're trying to do here. What's the type of 'velocities' ? Are you just trying to cast items into different types and add them, do you want to count the amount of items fo a particular type in a list, or are you trying something weird with reflection?

Comment: First, what I'm doing, then why I'm doing it. I could be going about this very, very wrong.

Velocities is an arraylist. Its going to be full of objects of type ValueAtTime. This is a tiny class that houses a float (the time) and a T(something logged at that time).

I'm not sure if T will be something I can use += on. It could be an int, a vector3, or a struct of 17 random values. I'm not sure. If it is something I can add up, though, I'd like to add it it. If I can't, I'd just like the last value in the arraylist.

Comment: Just saying but if the code inside the `if` statement is being run, `toReturn` will always equal `toAdd.Value`.

Comment: Wow. Comments have no linebreaks. Sorry. @matthew. If no exception is thrown, I should be getting the sum of the velocities. Am I wrong? Oh, wait. Finally will always be called, not matter what else. My C# is rusty. I'll find the appropriate be-all-end-all for a try-catch later, I guess.

Comment: And my goal. This is kind of my first step into game networking. This is going to be used to extrapolate the positions of objects since the last message from the server. Hence, I'm storing a bunch of changes to a value (maybe an objects position as a vector3, or a float describing its rotation) and adding it to the last official value I heard since contacting the server. I'm pretty early in writing this code, so I'd kind of like to leave it open what type of data I'm using this class to sync up. Hence, the generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of c#'s specific prohibition on try-catch in a generic, try catch should not be part of your standard operating method.  Your code relies on try-catch in order to overcome an obstacle.  That is utterly the wrong use of it.  Try-catch is meant to test operations that might fail for uncontrollable (or at least unpredictable) circumstances, and shut down or retry that operation.  It is extremely expensive for managed code to catch the error, and it's not meant to be a logical control mechanism.

**Edit** I did come up with an alternative, based on your comments explaining your question.  You are operating on varying game objects.  That doesn't require a generic; it requires an interface.  If all your objects implement the interface `IhasValueAtTime` with a method `float getValueAtTime(float time)`, then you can create a function like so `float addTwoGetValueAtTimeObjectsSum(IhasValueAtTime item1, IhasValueAtTime item2)`

Comment: Then offer a viable alternative.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I meant to answer the parts of the question "why can't I do this?", and "is not what try catch was built for".  I think I did that.

Comment: Well, I agree that it's not considered great form, but sometimes its convenient to simply swallow the exception or perform some alternate operation, especially if performance is not an issue.

Comment: You're probably right. Let me ask it another way. Why doesn't C# give me a way to test if a generic supports a particular function (such as +=) instead of dismissing it out of hand.

Comment: The interface idea is complicated, but +1 anyway, because it should work.

Comment: @tavoe Robert's technical explanation above is beyond my understand of c#.  If you really want to keep the try-catch, you could place it around the operation that uses your generic operator.  The error would still happen, but you could catch it and return to the last object you tried to add.

Comment: I think I'll give it a shot. Its got a certain panache to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are expecting different behaviour from 
`toReturn += toAdd.Value` and  `toReturn = toReturn + toAdd.Value`. They are (almost) exactly the same. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx) for further detail.

So when your try throws an exception, your catch will throw the same exception. I think that you would do better to do something like.

```
 T toReturn = officalValue.Value;

float maxValue;
velocities.Sort();
foreach(ValueAtTime<T> toAdd in velocities)
{
    if(toAdd.AtTime < time)
    {
        try
        {
            toReturn += toAdd.Value;
        }
        catch(OpperatorUnavailableError err)
        {
            toReturn = toAdd.Value;
            break; 
        }
    }
}
return toReturn;
```

Comment: The problem is that the code can't compile. C# doesn't allow you to use operators on generics. The point is that it doesn't throw an imaginary error OpperatorUnavailableError or anything at all. It won't even make the attempt. I was just wondering if there's a why to it.

Comment: @tavoe: You have to cast it to some type that the compiler can recognize as having the `+` or the `+=` operator defined.  The compiler is saying that it can't apply the operator because it has no way of knowing what type you are going to pass into it, and therefore no way of binding the operator at compile time.  To bind operators or methods at runtime, you have to use a `dynamic` object.

Comment: @robert. I tried that. I could go down the list of everything I expect. If(toReturn is int)... if(toReturn is float)... etc. There are two problems with that. First, I can't guess everything that might impliment +=, which is probably ok. Realistically, I'm only going to use this with about five fill-in-the-blanks for T. The other problem is that I get an error, saying that the as operator must be used with a non nullable type.

Comment: @tavoe: You tried the `+=` operator on a collection of `dynamic` values?  I suspect that if the values are `dynamic` (I think you can just cast them to `dynamic`), then you'll be able to get the behavior you expect, which is to trap an exception if the operator doesn't exist on the type captured in each of the `dynamic` values.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `T` is a generic parameter to a class/struct which contains your method. Now, I don't know what generic constraints you put on `T`, but is not possible to constrain `T` to only types which overload the `+` operator.

Therefore, this can not be done if `T` is a generic parameter.

What types are you using for `T`? Simple types like `int`, `double` and `decimal` which have "native" support for `+` in the language, or user-defined types which overload the `+` operator?